# How to address the relationship between step children and step parents?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is 'step motherhood' an appropriate word to describe the relationship between step parents step children?

Answer (score 2):

**Stepmotherhood** (or step motherhood or step-motherhood) is a possibility, although **stepparenting** is more common. The latter is defined in [Webster's New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stepparenting) as a noun meaning "parenting within a stepfamily".

[Stepmotherhood](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stepmotherhood) is in Wiktionary but not in most, more traditional dictionaries. However searching [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=stepmotherhood&btnG=) shows it is used in academic papers. It's also the title of a book by Cherie Burns (2nd ed, Crown Publications, 2003).

Stepparenting is in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stepparenting) and [Webster's College](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stepparenting) dictionaries while stepmotherhood isn't, suggesting it's more accepted as a word, and might be a better choice. Although it isn't in all dictionaries.

Finally, [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stepmotherhood%2Cstepfatherhood%2Cstepparenting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that stepparenting is much more common than stepmotherhood or stepfatherhood.

Whether you hyphenate or run together or put as two separate words is a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

In most situations you don't need a special word. The duties and responsibilities of a step-parent are the same as a biological parent.

If a distinction does need to be made, I'd prefer a phrase to a word: "Being a stepmother".

> It is hard being a stepmother to a teenager.

Is a lot better than

> Stepmotherhood is difficult when your stepchild is a teenager.